# How to control running order between threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

Following is structure of processing data and printing results. Some contents will be printed out during `process_records`, so I want for all threads `ensure` part can be printed out at very end of program running together **with order**, like first thread's ensure part should be printed out first. How can I do that without moving `print_report` out of `Thread.new do`? Thanks

```
lock = Mutex.new()
thread_num.times do |i|
    threads << Thread.new do
             records = lock.synchronize{db_proxy.query(account_id)}

             result1 = process_records(records) 
             result2 = process_records2(records)
             result3 = process_records3(records)
             ensure
                 print_report(result1, result2, result3)
             end
        }        
    end
end
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23766882/10522579)

Comment: To synchronise several threads to proceed together, typically one would use a barrier. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769241/240443)

Comment: I have [posted](https://dev.to/mudasobwa/reactor-pattern-in-ruby-47md) a very detailed example a while ago.

Comment: Actually, I misread your question. Using the barrier pattern as @Amadan suggests is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah. So ensure the barrier gets processed.